# Where and how to set up a function which is doing GET request every second?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to setup a function which will be working somewhere on the server. It is a simple GET request and I want to trigger it every second.

I tried google cloud functions and AWS. Both of them don't have a straightforward solution to run it every second. (every 1 minute only)

Could you please suggest me a service, or combination of services that will allow me to do it. (preferably not costly)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options on AWS ...

Launch a t2.nano EC2 instance to run a script that issues GET, then sleeps for 1 second, and repeats. You can't use cron (doesn't support every second). This costs about 13 cents per day.

If you are going to do this for months/years then reduce the cost by using Reserved Instances.

If you can tolerate periods where the GET requests don't happen then reduce the cost even further by using Spot instances.

That said, why do you need to issue a GET request every second? Perhaps there is a better solution here.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer!

I need GET request to see if the available slots for appointment is available.
I want to make it as often as possible, because people are taking all the slots immediately.

What if I reduce it to 5 seconds or even 10 seconds ? Will it be easier to find cheap solution ?

Comment: Reducing the frequency to once every 10 seconds won't change the cost - you're still basically going to need compute 24x7, whether it's EC2 or a sequence of Lambda functions. I'm assuming you're trying to automate detection of a free appointment slot at a third-party site - be aware that you might be violating their terms of service and may be blacklisted, or worse.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a AWS Lambda function, which simply loops and issues the GET request every second, and exits after 240 requets (i.e. 4 minutes). Then create a CloudWatch event that fires every 4 minutes calling the Lambda function.

Every 4 minutes because the maximum timeout you can set for a Lambda function is 5 minutes.

This setup will likely incur only some trivial cost:

- At 1 event per 4 minutes, it's $1/month for the CloudWatch events generated.
- At 1 call per 4 minutes to a minimally configured (128MB) Lambda function, it's 324,000 GB-second worth of execution per month, just within the free tier of 400,000 GB-second.
- Since network transfer into AWS is free, the response size of your GET request is irrelevant. And the first 1GB of transfer out to the Internet is free, which should cover all the GET requests themselves.

Comment: Thanks!
Great answer!

I just was not sure about the price of this solution.

Comment: @Alexandr see the answer updated with some more detailed price calculation.